# Factorial Summation Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, factorial

$$\sum_{j=0}^n j\cdot j!$$

I got $(n+1)!-1$ as the answer but I'm not sure if that's right or how I even got to that answer exactly. (my paper is a mess of random work and I can't make it out). Can somebody tell me if that's correct and explain the best and condensed way to get to the answer?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910466/) for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Write $j \cdot j! = (j+1)j! - j! = (j+1)!-j!$. Now you have a telescoping sum.

Alternatively, you can prove that statement using mathematical induction.

Answer (score 0):

Try a telescoping sum, like so
$$(n+1)! - 0! = \sum_{k-1}^n \left( (k+1)! - k!\right).$$
Can you bring it home?